# FaunaDB: How to paginate/count all documents within the last n days

Tags: faunadb

Pretty much was the title says.

Preferably using the built-in `ts` timestamp, not an additional field in `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For paginating/counting you can create an index like this:

`CreateIndex({name:"all_docs_ts",source:collection:Collection('test'),values:[{field:['ts']},{field:['ref']}]})`

and you can then paginate documents using a query like this:

`Paginate(Range(Match('all_docs_ts'),[ToMicros(ToTime('2020-07-14T06:30:00Z'))],[ToMicros(ToTime('2020-07-14T18:59:59Z'))]))`

If you want to get the **ref** for the returned document, you can use a query like this:

`Map(Paginate(Range(Match('all_docs_ts'),[ToMicros(ToTime('2020-07-14T06:30:00Z'))],[ToMicros(ToTime('2020-07-14T18:59:59Z'))])),Lambda(['ts','ref'],Var('ref')))`

or to get the full documents:

`Map(Paginate(Range(Match('all_docs_ts'),[ToMicros(ToTime('2020-07-14T06:30:00Z'))],[ToMicros(ToTime('2020-07-14T18:59:59Z'))])),Lambda(['ts','ref'],Get(Var('ref'))))`

For counting just use the **Count()** function:

`Count(Paginate(Range(Match('all_docs_ts'),[ToMicros(ToTime('2020-07-14T06:30:00Z'))],[ToMicros(ToTime('2020-07-14T18:59:59Z'))])))`

Please remember, by default **Paginate()** return **64** document per page. You can increase the batch to a maximum of **100000** documents:

`Paginate(........., {size:100000})`

If the resultset is bigger then **size**, you have to iterate over cursor using **after** and **before** (you can find a tutorial [here](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/indexes/pagination)).

Comment: Jep, that worked. I found a couple of ways to improve it, such as using `TimeSubtract`, but the basic structure is the same. 
The fact that I have to use `ToMicros` makes me wonder if storing a proper `Date` type in data would have been the better solution though.

Comment: Hi qwtel, 

it very depends on your needs. The **ts** field coming for free for each Fauna document, and it stores the create or last update for this specific document. You can create your own field in data that sore a **Date** representing the timestamp you want to filter with, but in that case you have to create the index accordingly.